# what is the difference between lambda and function in class in TS?

Tags: typescript, class

```js
class Person {
    name: string;
    age: number;
  
  constructor(name: string, age: number) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
  
  getAge() {
    return this.age;
  }
  
  getName = () => {
      return this.name;
  }
}
```

`getAge` is normal function. `getName` is lambda function. Is there a difference between these in `this` context?

Comment: getAge is on prototype.

Comment: And `getName` closes over the `this` value, i.e. it's set at declaration time rather than at runtime (so the value cannot change even if you do something like `const x = { f: new Person().getName }; x.f();` - the `this` value of a regular function would be `x`, but with the lambda/arrow function it remains the `Person` instance.

Comment: In use, this means that you can safely destructure `getName` from an instance, but not `getAge`: `const {getName} = new Person('name', Infinity); getName(); //=> "name"`